# Split dataframe into list of multiple dataframes based on multiple columns and select specific columns for each nested dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, nested, nested-lists

I have a dataframe like this:

```
|DOI                           | WoS| Scopus| Dim| WoS_Year| Scopus_Year| Dim_Year|
|:-----------------------------|---:|------:|---:|--------:|-----------:|--------:|
|10.1515/jag-2017-0010         |  NA|      1|   1|       NA|        2017|     2017|
|10.1007/978-3-662-55771-6_9   |  NA|     NA|   1|       NA|          NA|     2020|
|10.1088/1361-6668/30/2/024004 |   1|      1|  NA|     2017|        2017|       NA|
|10.3390/ma12010124            |   1|      1|  NA|     2019|        2019|       NA|
|10.1002/ppsc.201700109        |   1|      1|   1|     2017|        2017|     2017|
```

I want to split it into **a list of 3 dataframes** (`list_of_df`), whereby:

- **WoS**: `list_of_df$WoS` should have all `DOI` that have `WoS = 1`, and a column `Year` that resembles the old `WoS_Year`;
- **Scopus**: `list_of_df$Scopus` should have all `DOI` that have `Scopus= 1`, and a column `Year` resembling the old `Scopus_Year`;
- **Dim**: `list_of_df$Dim` should have all `DOI` that have `Dim= 1`, and a column `Year` resembling the old `Dim_Year`.

(There are actually multiple columns starting with `WoS_*` or `Scopus_*` or `Dim_*`, each of which I wish to keep in the new respective `list_of_df`, but by dropping the starting strings like `WoS_` etc.

E.g., all columns that are `starting_with("Scopus_")` should be in `list_of_df$Scopus` but without `Scopus_` in the column name.)

What would be the best approach to reach this goal?

My attempts with `list_of_df <- split(df, with(df, interaction(WoS,Scopus,Dim)), drop = TRUE)` or with `dplyr::nest(df, WoS:Dim)` did not bear fruits...

Thank you for your help!

```
> dput(df)

structure(list(DOI = c("10.1515/jag-2017-0010", "10.1007/978-3-662-55771-6_9", 
"10.1088/1361-6668/30/2/024004", "10.3390/ma12010124", "10.1002/ppsc.201700109"
), WoS = c(NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L), Scopus = c(1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L
), Dim = c(1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L), WoS_Year = c(NA, NA, 2017L, 2019L, 
2017L), Scopus_Year = c(2017L, NA, 2017L, 2019L, 2017L), Dim_Year = c(2017L, 
2020L, NA, NA, 2017L)), row.names = c(2186L, 9505L, 12281L, 11882L, 
874L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you could do:

```
df1 <- subset(reshape(df, matrix(2:ncol(df),2, byrow=TRUE), dir="long", idvar = "DOI", 
                       times = c("WoS","Scopus","Dim")), WoS==1)
rownames(df1)<-NULL
split(df1, df1$time)

$Dim
                           DOI time WoS WoS_Year
8        10.1515/jag-2017-0010  Dim   1     2017
9  10.1007/978-3-662-55771-6_9  Dim   1     2020
10      10.1002/ppsc.201700109  Dim   1     2017

$Scopus
                            DOI   time WoS WoS_Year
4         10.1515/jag-2017-0010 Scopus   1     2017
5 10.1088/1361-6668/30/2/024004 Scopus   1     2017
6            10.3390/ma12010124 Scopus   1     2019
7        10.1002/ppsc.201700109 Scopus   1     2017

$WoS
                            DOI time WoS WoS_Year
1 10.1088/1361-6668/30/2/024004  WoS   1     2017
2            10.3390/ma12010124  WoS   1     2019
3        10.1002/ppsc.201700109  WoS   1     2017
```

You could change the column names to match what you want

Another way:

```
lapply(split.default(df[-1],sub("_.*","",names(df[-1]))),
        function(x)na.omit(cbind(df[1], x)[x[[1]]==1,]))
$Dim
                             DOI Dim Dim_Year
2186       10.1515/jag-2017-0010   1     2017
9505 10.1007/978-3-662-55771-6_9   1     2020
874       10.1002/ppsc.201700109   1     2017

$Scopus
                                DOI Scopus Scopus_Year
2186          10.1515/jag-2017-0010      1        2017
12281 10.1088/1361-6668/30/2/024004      1        2017
11882            10.3390/ma12010124      1        2019
874          10.1002/ppsc.201700109      1        2017

$WoS
                                DOI WoS WoS_Year
12281 10.1088/1361-6668/30/2/024004   1     2017
11882            10.3390/ma12010124   1     2019
874          10.1002/ppsc.201700109   1     2017
```

Comment: The second solution with `lapply` is immensely elegant ... thank you! (But is there a way to get rid of the `WoS_*`, `Scopus_*` in the final column names?) I think I should integrate  user2974591's `colnames()` and `gsub()` into the `lapply`-function, but I am not 100% sure how to do that.

Comment: `lapply(split.default(df[-1],sub("_.*","",names(df[-1]))),
        function(x)na.omit(cbind(df[1], setNames(x, sub("_.*","", names(x))))[x[[1]]==1,]))` should work

Answer (score 1):

Another one in base R, if this is the expected output

```
res=list()
for (k in c("WoS","Scopus","Dim")) {
  res[[k]]=df[df[,k]==1 & !is.na(df[,k]),grepl(k,colnames(df)) | c(TRUE,rep(FALSE,ncol(df)-1))]
  colnames(res[[k]])=gsub(paste0(k,"_"),"",colnames(res[[k]]))
}

$WoS
                                DOI WoS Year
12281 10.1088/1361-6668/30/2/024004   1 2017
11882            10.3390/ma12010124   1 2019
874          10.1002/ppsc.201700109   1 2017

$Scopus
                                DOI Scopus Year
2186          10.1515/jag-2017-0010      1 2017
12281 10.1088/1361-6668/30/2/024004      1 2017
11882            10.3390/ma12010124      1 2019
874          10.1002/ppsc.201700109      1 2017

$Dim
                             DOI Dim Year
2186       10.1515/jag-2017-0010   1 2017
9505 10.1007/978-3-662-55771-6_9   1 2020
874       10.1002/ppsc.201700109   1 2017
```

Comment: That's wonderful, thank you so much! For some reason it drops my `DOI` column though. Do you happen to know why this might be the case?

Comment: @anpami Hard to tell, but I did assume that that the DOI column was at position 1 in the original dataframe, has this changed? That's what the stuff to the right of | does in the first line of the loop.

Comment: Ah, you are right. My code added an `X` column... so after `df[1] <- NULL` it worked again. Thank you. While I love your code (thanks a lot!), I think I have to accept @Onyambu's second solution with `lapply`. The reason is that Onyambu's `lapply`-solution is so abstract & general that it works with any characters in the columns names (i.e., not just with `WoS_`, `Scopus_` and `Dim_`, but with any other ones that happen to be there). I find this most elegant. But nevertheless, thanks for the solution!